# Validation error even is Drop Down value selected by Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, python, selenium, ui-automation

I am automating the website testing using selenium, I have a scenario in which I need to fill the drop-down mandatory. I am filling the drop-down value using below code which is working fine:

```
select = Select(find_element_by_name('feet')
select.select_by_value("5")
```

Now the problem is when I click on Next button after selecting a drop-down value(5) using automation script, it throws validation error saying: "Please select the value from the drop-down".

I have tried to execute javascript from browser console as well and received the same result.

But when I select the drop-down value manually Next button is taking me to other page and it's working fine.

**So the bottom line is If I use automation script in order to select the drop-down value browser will not detect the change made to the drop down, hence when I click on Next button it throws the validation error**

Any help/hint on this highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried with explicit wait ?

Comment: What if you `click()` on `<Select>` and after `click()` on element from list which appear? Like a real human.

Comment: Yes that is the last solution for me.!

Answer (score 0):

You can try explicit wait after selecting 5 from drop down:

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'button id')))
```

Note that you have to import :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

For more you can refer this link :

[Selenium_Python_Binding](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: 1) Button has nothing to do with Wait, I tried to put 15-second static wait though it's still giving validation error while clicking.
2) The Button is already clickable so I could not put this condition.

Comment: FYI , this is to explicitly tell your web driver to wait till it becomes clickable , how do you know that it is clickable ? It comes as best practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select selectvalue = new Select(
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("test")));
selectvalue.selectByVisibleText("dropdownvalue");
```

By this you can click on any value from dropdown but make sure use **wait**

Comment: Wait is not playing any role here.
1) Button has nothing to do with Wait, I tried to put 15-second static wait though it's still giving validation error while clicking. 2) The Button is already clickable so I could not put this condition